# Oreo, foreground service stops when closed

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I am using service as foreground one.
on android pre O versions everything works fine.
but in android Oreo when i close app, the foreground service also closed...

here how i start service:

```
val i = Intent(activity, MyService::class.java)
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(activity, i)
```

and than inside service `onStart`:

```
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MY_CHANEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)

        val notification = builder.build()

        startForeground(notificationId, notification)
```

service in manifest:

```
        <service
            android:name=".data.service.MyService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            />
```

any idea why it closed with app and how prevent it?

thanks!

Comment: i think you have to ask user to check if auto-start of your application service is active or not

Comment: how it can be related with finishing foreground service???

Comment: What do you mean by close app? Are you starting a sticky service?

Comment: can u make a simple app and upload source of it? Can't reproduce that behavior of foreground service

Comment: @AndrewBrowiski noticed it few days ago: this is some kind of bug in my onePlus 3T os version(install last one beta). cos my friend that has same phone as me also chack this issue and there is no problem on his device.

Comment: @Andriy Antonov: Did you get any solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `JobIntentService` instead of `Service`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html